# How can i get the number of items(option) in a HTML select box in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation, html-select

How can i get the number of items(option) in a HTML select box in jQuery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see how many elements a selector matched, for example:

```
var count = $("#selectID option").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
     var count =$('select#myID > option').size();
     alert(count);

});
```

Comment: @ScottE - Actually, the `>` in this case should probably not be used since an `<option>` isn't necessarily a direct child of the `<select>`.